# False Alarm on HIbernate: HHH000262: Table not found

Tags: java, hibernate

I have just moved my development environment. Faster PC with locally installed -

- PostgresSql 9.6.
- Hibernate 5.0.7.Final

There is no change in the beans.xml file. The development environment is the same as on two other boxes. The other two boxes have no problem.

When I run a Hibernate/Spring app on the new development environment, I get the following error at startup for every table in the database:

> 17:00:13.617 [ikoda.jobanalysis.JobAnalysisApplication.main()] INFO 
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl
>   - HHH000262: T able not found: CountJobTitle

BUT the application then goes to work and connects to the tables without a problem. I am certain it is reading the correct beans.xml file.

So why am I getting this information at startup?

```html
 <!-- Hibernate 192.168.0.27 en degree level-->
 <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
  <property name="jdbcUrl"
   value="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.27/xxxx?useUnicode=true&#38;characterEncoding=utf8" />
  <property name="user" value="xxx" />
  <property name="password" value="xxx" />


  <property name="acquireIncrement" value="2" />
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="3" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
  <property name="maxIdleTime" value="600" />
 </bean> 



 <!-- Hibernate session factory -->

 <bean id="sessionFactoryjobs"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource">
   <ref bean="dataSource" />
  </property>




  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    <prop key="temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</prop>
    <prop key="show_sql">false</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>

   </props>
  </property>
```